# How to get all matches in strings that are located between double curly brackets?

Tags: c#, regex

How to get all matches in a text

```
 string text={{string1}}{{string2}}{{string3}}{{string4}};
```

and returns

```
string1
string2
string3
string4
```

Comment: What is a match in your case? What is the pattern for a match?

Comment: Using regex :             string text=   "{{string1}}{{string2}}{{string3}}{{string4}}";
            string pattern = @"\{(?'text'[\w]+)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["text"].Value).ToArray()));
            Console.ReadLine();